# Exception of type 'MS.Internal.Validate+Validation Failure' was thrown

Tags: wpf, xaml

Drag dropping a button onto my WPF form is erroring, I've also tried typing the xaml for a button (same error)

it pops up the error 'MS.Internal.Validated+Validation Failure' was thrown

and then after that pops up the screen goes white and shows this :

```
Exception of type 'MS.Internal.Validate+ValidationFailure' was thrown.
at MS.Internal.Validate.Retail(Boolean value)
at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTreeManagers.ItemUpdater.ApplyDelta(INodeHost 
nodeHost, DeltaItemCollection delta, ModifiableDocumentTree root, DocumentNodeDictionary 
oldTable, Boolean updateTable, DocumentNodeDictionary deletedItems, Comparison`1 compare)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.DocumentTreeManager.ApplyDelta(Delta delta, 
Comparison`1 compare)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.ApplyUpdate(Delta delta)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.IncrementalRebuild(DocumentTreeManager 
tree, Damage damage)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.UpdateView(DocumentTreeManager tree, Damage 
damage)
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.ViewProducer.UpdateView(UpdateDamageArguments args)
```

This is seemingly random considering i was editing this form on friday without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by opening the same project in visual studio 2012 edition instead of using 2010 (If i go to add a button in this it works like normal)

Note that this isn't really the best solution (Considering not everyone has a copy of vs 2012 to just switch to)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar error (At least the same Validation failure part) in my WPF Form.
In my case, I was able to solve it by closing and reopening visual studio and simply choosing "Rebuild" on the project.